# Concatenating columns in a two-dimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists of strings similar to this one:

```
arr = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
       ['1', '2', '3'],
      ]
```

which I need to convert to a list of concatenated "columns", i.e.:

```
['aX1', 'bY2', 'cZ3']
```

I came up with the solution of rotating the entire array 90 degrees clockwise, then joining all items in each rows in reverse order:

```
[''.join(reversed(row)) for row in zip(*reversed(arr))]
```

This works as long as each row has the same number of items. What if that's not the case, though. Say I have an array like this:

```
arr = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
       ['X', 'Y'],
       ['1', '2', '3'],
      ]
```

and what I expect is:

```
['aX1', 'bY2', 'c3', 'd']
```

I could pad the shorter rows with empty string items prior to using the solution above:

```
max_item_count = max(len(row) for row in arr)
arr = [row + [''] * (max_item_count - len(row)) for row in arr]
```

But surely there's a better way?

Comment: [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have lists of different lengths, you could make use of [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) which allows a fill value to be specified:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> arr = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['X', 'Y'], ['1', '2', '3']]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in zip_longest(*arr, fillvalue='')]  
['aX1', 'bY2', 'c3', 'd']
```

The shorter lists are padded using this fill value up to the length of the longest list.

In Python 2, the function is named `izip_longest`.

Comment: Note that it's just `zip_longest` in 3.x (as the basic `zip` is now an iterator).